# How to request API data with $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, mean.io

I'm developing an app with Riot Games API but this example it's done with [REST Countries API](https://restcountries.eu/). https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha/co

I use a MEAN.IO stack and this is my code:

test.html

```
<html ng-app="lolData">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

   <section id="center" ng-controller="summonerStats">
      <form ng-submit="search()">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="summonerName" placeholder="Summoner Name">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1"></label>
        </div>
        <input class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" type="submit" value="Search"/>           

      <p ng-show="show">
        {{ mystats.name }}
      </p>

    </form>
   </section>   
</body> 
</html>
```

test.js

```
'use strict';

var lolData = angular.module('lolData', []);
console.log("before controller");

lolData.controller('summonerStats', function($scope, $http) {        
   var url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha/co";
   console.log("inside controller");
   $scope.show = false;       
   $scope.search = function() {                                                          
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.mystats = response;
        $scope.show = true;
        console.log("inside success controller");
    });
};                
});
```

When I refresh the page the code is executed until "before controller" console.log. It can't get inside lolData.controller. And in the browser console displays the following error.

[image: Error: ng:areq]

And html doesn't accept the embeded javascript scope.

[image: {{ mystats.name }}]

What am I missing?

Update 1:

I added the index.html in a codepen: [Index.html](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaWYRe)

And Header.html in a codepen too: [header.html](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pywvYZ)

Comment: Can you show index.html please?

Comment: yes, where do you plugin angular.js?

Comment: Check browser dev tools network. Sounds like that file isn't loading. No script tags for angular or your app scripts are shown

Comment: I already added index and header html. Each one has diferent controller but nothing about ng-app.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your problem, but `$http.success` (and `$http.error`) has been [depreciated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/docs/api/ng/service/$http) since v1.4.4. Instead, use callback functions for success and error

```
var url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha/co";
$http.get(url).then(
  function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.mystats = response;
    $scope.show = true;
    console.log("inside success controller");
  }, function errorCallback(error) {
     console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Better with your code. I want something that's not deprecated. But the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your response object doesn't do what you think it does.

From [angular's docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you see the response has multiple properties attached to the returned object.

You want

`$scope.mystats = JSON.parse(response.data);`

Comment: Nothing changed with JSON.parse(response.data); Maybe it's because the API already return JSON right?

Comment: Have you done a `console.log(response)` in the callback?

Comment: Yes I did and only displays the areq error. I think it's something about declare in a correct way. But I don't find where. I also put the ng-app inside tag <html>.